# Clean architecture: Use CompositeDisposable in domain or presentation/app

Tags: android, clean-architecture

I just start learn and apply `CleanArchitecture` for my Android project.
I see there are 2 great source for following here
1) https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture
2) https://github.com/fiveagency/Reedly (https://five.agency/android-architecture-part-4-applying-clean-architecture-on-android-hands-on/)

Currently, the first source use the `CompositeDisposable` in [domain (inside `UseCase`)](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture/blob/master/domain/src/main/java/com/fernandocejas/android10/sample/domain/interactor/UseCase.java) and the second source use in [presentation/app(`Presenter`/`ViewModel`)](https://github.com/fiveagency/Reedly/blob/master/app/src/main/java/oxim/digital/reedly/base/BasePresenter.java)

As my current understand, I see the benefit when we put `CompositeDisposable` in `Presenter/ViewModel`.

- Easy to dispose (because if we `CompositeDisposable` in `UseCase`, for each `UseCase` we need to dispose call 1 time)
- May easy to combine many `UseCase` (eg: `UseCase1` execute then flatMap/zip... with `UseCase2`)

I see the benefit when we put `CompositeDisposable` in `UseCase`

- It separate `RX` from presentation

I don't know if is there any other pros/cons of 2 approach. I never use `CleanArchitecture` for real project and I know when we follow any approach, it's quite hard to change to another approach.

For me, currently I think I will choose: put `CompositeDisposable` in `UseCase`. 
What should I use? Is there any other approach?
Any help or advice would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to clean architecture, I have been using **1) Android-CleanArchitecture** for about a year now. And when it comes to disposing `CompositeDisposable`, I would do it in `Presenter` if I were you, because it is closely related to life-cycle of View and it controls data flow which `CompositeDisposable` in this case kind of belongs to.

**Suggestion:**

Convert **1) Android-CleanArchitecture** from MVP to MVVM in *Presentation layer* with [ViewModels](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) and dispose your `CompositeDisposable` there. MVVM with Googles new ViewModel library eliminates headaches of managing life-cylce dependent objects yourself, which MVP in this `CleanArchitecutre` template fails to deliver.

---

Hope this cleared things up a bit. Good Luck :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. However, I still don't know about this part `it controls data flow which CompositeDisposable in this case kind of belongs to`

Comment: By saying that I mean that `Presenter` is responsible for triggering Domain events (interactors/use cases) and that is why `Presenter` should also be the one that is clearing (disposing) those event instances. Did I make it more clear for you? By the way, you should not be concerned about separating RX from presentation layer as it can be used not only for data requests.

Comment: To be more concrete you should dispose them in `Presenter` using `UseCase` instance that has `CompositeDisposable` in it. It is actually already implemented like that in **1)** template.

Comment: Thank you for your explain. I understand it more clearly. Beside that, I see if we put the CompositeDisposable to Presenter/ViewModel, the code look more simple than put in Usecase. I think it may be a good point